# JavaScript outputting incorrect html

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am having a problem doing this real time message system. For some reason the JavaScript is not rendering the html element `<p>` tag properly. The message comes out as it should, however, in a `<p>` tag that was not specified. It is rendering without the message in the `"<p class='text-left bg-primary'>" "</p>"` and the `"<p class='text-left bg-success'>" "</p>"`. Note that these classes are affiliated with Twitter Bootstap. When I check the html element this is what is rendered instead:

[image]

So the correct `<p>` tag is not being rendered with `data.message`, but also it is producing two other unwanted `<p>` tags, one of which has the desired message. Why is the JavaScript outputting more than one `<p>` tags and also not putting the `data.message` within the right `<p>` tag? The code is below. I also tried the code with the Bootstap class and ran into the same problem.

```
var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
var username = '{{ request.user.username }}';
var sender_username = data.sender_username;
var content = "";
var newdiv = "";
// See if there's a div to replace it in, or if we should add a new one
var existing = $("div[data-message-id=" + data.id + "]");

if(sender_username == username)
{
    console.log(sender_username);
    content = "<p class='text-left bg-primary'>" + data.message + "</p>";
    console.log(data.id);
    if (existing.length)
    {
        console.log("sender div to replace");
        existing.html(content);
    }
    else
    {
        newdiv = $("<div class='message' data-message-id='" + data.id + "'>" + content + "</div>");
        $("#messages").append(newdiv);
        console.log("sender no existing div");
    }
}
else
{
    content = "<p class='text-left bg-warning'>" + data.message + "</p>";
    if (existing.length)
    {
        console.log("receiver div to replace");
        existing.html(content);
    }
    else
    {
        newdiv = $("<div class='message' data-message-id='" + data.id + "'>" + content + "</div>");
        $("#messages").append(newdiv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show all the code,  as the declaration of `existing` is missing

Comment: @ChrisSatchell done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely the `data.message` is html and looks like `'<p>div test 9</p>'` which closes your `p` tag that contains the classes. the last empty `p` tag is common if the text comes from a cms and the user added a return to the end when using the wysiwyg editor.

you can strip all of the html:

```
if(sender_username == username)
{

    //strip all of the html tags and return only the text
    var message = $('<div />').html(data.message).text();

    content = "<p class='text-left bg-primary'>" + message + "</p>";

    if (existing.length)
    {
        console.log("sender div to replace");
        existing.html(content);
    }
    else
    {
        newdiv = $("<div class='message' data-message-id='" + data.id + "'>" + content + "</div>");
        $("#messages").append(newdiv);
        console.log("sender no existing div");
    }
}
else
{
    content = "<p class='text-left bg-warning'>" + data.message + "</p>";
    if (existing.length)
    {
        console.log("receiver div to replace");
        existing.html(content);
    }
    else
    {
        newdiv = $("<div class='message' data-message-id='" + data.id + "'>" + content + "</div>");
        $("#messages").append(newdiv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Joel, I do not understand what you are saying about the first part. However I understand what you said about the last `p` which is coming from a CMS.

Comment: edited my answer to show how you can strip the html tags. i recommend doing this on your server side (wherever data.message comes from)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hmmm. for some reason I am hard headed. It is working now. However I am still wondering why it was not treating it as `text` in the first place. It is not like I had any `html` tags in the `data.message`.

Comment: try console logging data.message. if that content comes from a cms wysiwyg editor, it will probably be html and wrapped in a p tag

Comment: Gotcha! it comes out as `<p><br />test 6</p>` in console log. That is for `data.message = test 6`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes much sense now! I do not think CMS editors should do these things. It is very bad!